# Liferay workflow Flow(ie:Kaleo WorkFlow)

Tags: liferay

I have a requirement.We have a form where we create users in liferay and it should go through approval process(ie:single approver).If the omni admin fills that form then the user must not go through approval process and when the same form is accessed by any other user it must go through approval processs.Am new to this 
can some one help me in writing the xml or any links .

I need the same reuiremnt like mentioned in this link.

liferayaddicts.net/blogs/-/blogs/conditional-transition-in-liferay-workflow-using-default-kaleo-engine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used the below workflow XML Code

```
<workflow-definition
    xmlns="urn:liferay.com:liferay-workflow_6.1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:liferay.com:liferay-workflow_6.1.0 http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-workflow-definition_6_1_0.xsd"
>
    <name>Sample</name>
    <description>A single approver can approve a workflow content.</description>
    <version>10</version>
    <state>
        <name>created</name>
        <metadata>
            <![CDATA[{"xy":[36,51]}]]>
        </metadata>
        <initial>true</initial>
        <transitions>
            <transition>
                <name>Determine Review</name>
                <target>review-or-approve</target>
                <default>true</default>
            </transition>
        </transitions>
    </state>
     <condition>
         <name>review-or-approve</name>
         <script> <![CDATA[
                         import com.liferay.portal.service.RoleLocalServiceUtil;
                         import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.GetterUtil;
                         import com.liferay.portal.kernel.workflow.WorkflowConstants;
                         try {
                                 returnValue = "Review";
                                 long userid = GetterUtil.getLong((String)workflowContext.get(WorkflowConstants.CONTEXT_USER_ID));
                                 long companyid = GetterUtil.getLong((String)workflowContext.get(WorkflowConstants.CONTEXT_COMPANY_ID));
                                 String[] roles={"JSM Admin"};
                                if (RoleLocalServiceUtil.hasUserRoles(userid, companyid, roles, true)) returnValue = "Approved";
                         } catch (Exception e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                         }
                    ]]> 
            </script>
         <script-language>beanshell</script-language>
        <transitions>
                 <transition>
                         <name>Review</name>
                         <target>review</target>
                         <default>false</default>
                 </transition>
                 <transition>
                         <name>Approved</name>
                         <target>approved</target>
                         <default>false</default>
                 </transition>
         </transitions>
     </condition>
    <task>
        <name>update</name>
        <metadata>
            <![CDATA[{"transitions":{"resubmit":{"bendpoints":[[303,140]]}},"xy":[328,199]}]]>
        </metadata>
        <actions>
            <action>
                <name>reject</name>
                <script>
                    <![CDATA[
                        Packages.com.liferay.portal.kernel.workflow.WorkflowStatusManagerUtil.updateStatus(Packages.com.liferay.portal.kernel.workflow.WorkflowConstants.toStatus("denied"), workflowContext);
                        Packages.com.liferay.portal.kernel.workflow.WorkflowStatusManagerUtil.updateStatus(Packages.com.liferay.portal.kernel.workflow.WorkflowConstants.toStatus("pending"), workflowContext);
                    ]]>
                </script>
                <script-language>javascript</script-language>
                <execution-type>onAssignment</execution-type>
            </action>
            <notification>
                <name>Creator Modification Notification</name>
                <template>Your submission was rejected by a reviewer, please modify and resubmit.</template>
                <template-language>text</template-language>
                <notification-type>email</notification-type>
                <execution-type>onAssignment</execution-type>
            </notification>
        </actions>
        <assignments>
            <user />
        </assignments>
        <transitions>
            <transition>
                <name>resubmit</name>
                <target>review</target>
            </transition>
        </transitions>
    </task>
    <task>
        <name>review</name>
        <metadata>
            <![CDATA[{"xy":[168,36]}]]>
        </metadata>
        <actions>
            <notification>
                <name>Review Notification</name>
                <template>You have a new submission waiting for your review in the workflow.</template>
                <template-language>text</template-language>
                <notification-type>email</notification-type>
                <execution-type>onAssignment</execution-type>
            </notification>
            <notification>
                <name>Review Completion Notification</name>
                <template>
                    Your submission has been reviewed and the reviewer has applied the following ${taskComments}.</template>
                <template-language>freemarker</template-language>
                <notification-type>email</notification-type>
                <recipients>
                    <user />
                </recipients>
                <execution-type>onExit</execution-type>
            </notification>
        </actions>
        <assignments>
            <roles>
                <role>
                    <role-type>organization</role-type>
                    <name>Organization Administrator</name>
                </role>
                <role>
                    <role-type>organization</role-type>
                    <name>Organization Content Reviewer</name>
                </role>
                <role>
                    <role-type>organization</role-type>
                    <name>Organization Owner</name>
                </role>
                <role>
                    <role-type>regular</role-type>
                    <name>Administrator</name>
                </role>
                <role>
                    <role-type>regular</role-type>
                    <name>Portal Content Reviewer</name>
                </role>
                <role>
                    <role-type>site</role-type>
                    <name>Site Administrator</name>
                </role>
                <role>
                    <role-type>site</role-type>
                    <name>Site Content Reviewer</name>
                </role>
                <role>
                    <role-type>site</role-type>
                    <name>Site Owner</name>
                </role>
            </roles>
        </assignments>
        <transitions>
            <transition>
                <name>approve</name>
                <target>approved</target>
            </transition>
            <transition>
                <name>reject</name>
                <target>update</target>
                <default>false</default>
            </transition>
        </transitions>
    </task>
    <state>
        <name>approved</name>
        <metadata>
            <![CDATA[
                {"xy":[380,51]}
            ]]>
        </metadata>
        <actions>
            <action>
                <name>approve</name>
                <script>
                    <![CDATA[
                        Packages.com.liferay.portal.kernel.workflow.WorkflowStatusManagerUtil.updateStatus(Packages.com.liferay.portal.kernel.workflow.WorkflowConstants.toStatus("approved"), workflowContext);
                    ]]>
                </script>
                <script-language>javascript</script-language>
                <execution-type>onEntry</execution-type>
            </action>
        </actions>
    </state>
</workflow-definition>
```

May be helpfull for others who want to use workflow